# autocomplete text is escaping text after #

Tags: angular, urlencode

```
return this.http.get(Configs.BASE_PATH + 'getTaxRates' + query +
                     '&ts='+ Date.now());
query = "?
```

The issue is that my search query is

303 E 14 mile Rd, #305, Clawson, MI 48017 and same is found while debugging in the above code

But in the network tab it is coming as

searchText: 303 E 14 mile Rd,

Everything after # is gettting escaped.

IS this a known angular issue?

Issue is coming in every version of angular

Comment: Some characters are not valid when used as-is in URLs, and so must be URL-encoded ([percent-encoded](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding)) when appearing in URLs. Hash (`'#'`) is an RFC 3986 section 2.2 Reserved Character

Comment: i am already encoding

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding the params to your request with:

```
  let params = new HttpParams();
   params = params.append('myParam', value);
   params = params.append('myOtherParam', value);

this.http.get(myUrl, {params: params});
```

I believe HttpParams will handled the encoding.

You will also need to add HttpParams to your existing http import e.g:

```
import { HttpClient, HttpParams } from '@angular/common/http';
```

Comment: i dont have the reputation to mark it as answer,Someone else please mark it as correct answer

Comment: Only you can mark as answered as it's your question. Just need to click the check icon